# Set Plotly Range Selector

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I am using plotly.express in Python with time series data, and I would like to set a rangeselector that allows me to select the first date of the time series + 1 day and the first date of the time series + 3 days. How can I achieve this?

I have attempted the following, but it seems to use the last date of the time series - 1 day and -3 days, and the stepmode only accepts backward and todate as acceptable values:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = px.line(df, x='Date', y='AAPL.High', title='Time Series with Range Slider and Selectors')

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeslider_visible=True,
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1, label="1d", step="day", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=3, label="3d", step="day", stepmode="backward")
        ])
    )
)
fig.show()
```